# How to get the file right click menu in windows explorer in Java

Tags: java, windows, swing, contextmenu

I am making a twin panel commander.

I made two JTables which displays the current directory contents. I would like to implement that a right click on a file would display the windows explorer shell context menu.

Is it somehow possible ?

Comment: *"two JTables which displays the current directory tree."* BTW - it seems odd you would a table to represent a tree.  See this [example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) which uses a `JTree` for the directory tree and a `JTable` for the directory list.

Comment: i would like to display the context menu in windows only. And JTables are fine. I've made a mistake i am only displaying current directory content... Not the whole tree. Sorry

Comment: What do you intend to do instead, for OS X & *nix users?

Comment: I prepared my own java context menu for these two platforms.

Comment: Figured that out :). I will post answer when i can because i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured that out with using external app [Runmenu](http://www.programbits.co.uk/downloads/runmenu.zip).

```
    String runMenuApp = "path\\to\\runmenu.exe /show "; 
    String file = "\"" + "path\\to\\fileordir" + "\"";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runMenuApp + file);
```